# Error while calling MindsDBs query endpoint using Python requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, mindsdb

I'm trying to call a MindsDBs query endpoint using Python requests library, but I am encountering an error. When I run the SQL query from DBeaver, it works correctly. However, when I try to call the same query endpoint using Python requests, I receive the following error:

```
{"message": "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

Here's my Python code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:47334/api/sql/query'
resp = requests.post(url, data={"query":"SELECT * FROM mytable"})
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Can someone help me resolve this error?

- I have checked that the MindsDB server is running on my local machine.
- I have also tried to call other MindsDB endpoints using Python requests, and they work correctly. This issue seems to be specific to the query endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a minor bug in the API docs, so instead of `data`, you will need to provide the `json` parameter as:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:47334/api/sql/query'
resp = requests.post(url, json={"query":"SELECT * FROM mytable"})
```